# Conditional density and Lévy processes (with application to option pricing)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Given a Brownian motion $X_t$, we know (by definition) that the density is $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 t}}$

Now, if our Brownian motion starts from a certain point $y$ instead of $0$, we consider the conditional density

$f(x,t|y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2 t}}$

Then, we can observe that (with a little abuse of notation)

$f(x,t|y)=f(x-y,t)$ or, omitting the time,

$f(x|y)=f(x-y)$.

My question is: Is this true for more general processes, such as Lévy processes? If so, why?

I have the impression that this should be true for any process with independent increments, but I actually don't know how to prove it. Somehow related to this, I also read the following: if we have a process with independent increments, such as a Lévy process, then the (conditional) characteristic function can be written as

$\psi(u|x)=e^{i u x} \phi(u)$.

The two statements are connected, aren't they ?

Could you provide me with some insights into this topic ?

Thank you very much for your help!! :)

Comment: I am not familiar with the Levy process. I just want to point out that in the very first example, since the Brownian motion is a Markov process, the condition just give a location shift (similar to a location parameter) and that's why you got the result.

Comment: Yes, the statement holds more generally for Lévy processes. More abstractly put, it holds that $$\mathbb{P}^x(X_t \in B) = \mathbb{P}^0(X_t-x \in B)$$ for any Borel set $B$.